# Dos funciones al mismo botón

Tags: android-studio

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements  View.OnClickListener{

    Button Button1, Button2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        findViewById(R.id.button).setOnClickListener(this);
        Button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        findViewById(R.id.button2).setOnClickListener(this);
        Button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);

    }

    public void onClick(View v) {

        if (v.getId() == R.id.button) {
            Button2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }



        if (v.getId() == R.id.button2){
            Button1.setText("Hola");
        }

    }
}
```

Si quiero que al volver apretar el botón1 se vuelva hacer visible el botón2 como podría hacerlo?

gracias!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes agregar una variable boolean para cambiar el estado:

```
private boolean habilita;
```

y realizar la validación:

```
if (v.getId() == R.id.button) {
    Button2.setVisibility(habilita?View.VISIBLE:View.INVISIBLE);
    habilita = !habilita;
}
```

de esta forma al dar clic al botón se estaría cambiando la visibilidad de Button2.